# Age from birthdate in python

Tags: python

How can I find an age in python from today's date and a persons birthdate? The birthdate is a from a DateField in a  Django model.

Comment: When standard `datetime` module is not enough, you can try: http://labix.org/python-dateutil

Comment: This has nearly certainly been resolved by: `dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta`

Answer (score 426, accepted):

That can be done much simpler considering that int(True) is 1 and int(False) is 0, and tuples comparison goes from left to right:

```
from datetime import date

def calculate_age(born):
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))
```

Comment: a nitpick: `date.today()` returns the date in the local timezone that may be different from the place of birth. You might need to [use timezones explicitly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32658742/4279)

Comment: That probably depends on your definition of "age". For all practical purposes a birthday is usually given as a date, not timezone-aware datetime (i.e., "born" is missing the details). Most people are not born at midnight sharp (so usually observe prematurely :-)), and when in a different timezone, I would assume that most people observe their birthday in the local time (that's what I do, I live 10-12h ahead of my birth place time). If "born" was a timezone-aware datetime, you could use pytz's arithmetic and normalize() - maybe of interest for an astrology software?

Comment: I agree completely in the context of human ages but your formula may be used in a wider context. Though I personally never celebrate my birthday even an hour earlier due to a family tradition and being a programmer it is trivial to calculate the time wherever I am.

Comment: @pyd: born is a date/datetime

Comment: It's not just that `int(True) == 1` and `int(False) == 0`, it turns out that Python allows you to add and subtract booleans from integers, so you don't even need to wrap the boolean values with `int`! TIL. `1 - True == 0` in Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Well that's the point - as you can see there is no int() in the code.
We're subtracting the boolean - the conversion (sometimes called "marshalling") is implicit. Just like you check the boolean values of integers `if amount`, no need to go `if bool(amount)`.

Answer (score 70):

```
from datetime import date

def calculate_age(born):
    today = date.today()
    try: 
        birthday = born.replace(year=today.year)
    except ValueError: # raised when birth date is February 29 and the current year is not a leap year
        birthday = born.replace(year=today.year, month=born.month+1, day=1)
    if birthday > today:
        return today.year - born.year - 1
    else:
        return today.year - born.year
```

**Update:** Use [Danny's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9754466/65387), it's better

Comment: I even go so far as to test the message of the exception to make sure its what I am expecting.  Even with the code above, there is a possibility that a ValueError is thrown, but its not the ValueError you are expecting.

Comment: + for exception but, Is there any problem in my [`def calculate_age(dob)`](http://codepad.org/gFx7lrmH) **?** I think it is quite simple.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Yes, yours doesn't work. `datetime.date(2014, 1, 1)` gives -1, it should give 0. Your `today > dob` is checking if the DOB is in the past, not earlier this same year. `datetime.date.today()` includes year information, which is why I replace it with the current year in my solution.

Comment: @Mark Hmm helpful I think I got your point. On the basis of your comment (and some search) I improved my function as [`def calculate_age(dob)`](http://codepad.org/uVufrI8d). In-case if I am still missing let know, Thank you very much Mark.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: That solution looks like it should work. Might want to try a few more dates, but I don't see any problems with it.

Comment: The previous version considered someone with DOB 2012-02-29 to be considered 1 year old on the 2013-02-28, which I don't. I've changed it so that they wouldn't be one year old until the 1st of March, which is how I see it. All tests pass.

Comment: @qris: Your change was (rightfully) rejected by the community. I, however, agree so I've re-instated it.

Comment: This seems overly long for the task, and imho also not efficient (whole new date through replace(), exception handling...). Just subtract the birth year from this year, and subtract a further 1 if the month and day are in the future - see my answer below. And of course the tuple (2, 29) is greater than the tuple (2, 28)...

Comment: @DannyW.Adair Can't deny that... I've linked your solution.

Answer (score 21):

```
from datetime import date

days_in_year = 365.2425    
age = int((date.today() - birth_date).days / days_in_year)
```

In Python 3, you could perform division on `datetime.timedelta`:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

age = (date.today() - birth_date) // timedelta(days=365.2425)
```

Comment: every fourth year is a leap year except evey hundredth year is not a leap year except every four hundredth year is a leap year. try days_in_year=365.2425

Comment: @Dan: the difference between Julian (`365.25`) and Gregorian calendar year (`365.2425`) is less than a day if you live less than 130 years.

Comment: This doesn't work for *some* dates:
`(date(2017, 3, 1) - date(2004, 3, 1)) / timedelta(days=365.2425)` should return `13`, but it returns `12`. Unfloored, the result is `12.999582469181433`.

Comment: This answer does not approach the quality and accuracy of the already accepted answer submitted in 2012. Why even bother to submit this answer which is essentially a distraction from the right answer?

Answer (score 20):

As suggested by @[Tomasz Zielinski] and @Williams [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) can do it just 5 lines.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
dob = date(1982, 7, 5)
age = relativedelta(today, dob)

>>relativedelta(years=+33, months=+11, days=+16)`
```

Comment: How do you get the age in total days?

Comment: This doesn't even answer the question and even if adjusted to provide years instead of days does not even approach the quality and accuracy of the already accepted answer submitted in 2012 which provides a whole method to actually answer the query in 4 lines. Why people even submit these "answers" I can only guess is for some sort of accolade from how many comments they make but why people even vote them up I don't know.

Comment: @NeilG the question is "How can I find an age in python from today's date and a persons birthdate? ". We lesser souls submit these answers to help fellow lesser souls who are trying to find way to move ahead in their learning. Multiple asnwers help we lesser souls to look at various solutions to a problem. One solultion though correct may not be suiting them in their overall application setup, so multiple answers provide them perspective. And please don't guess "In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess."

Comment: @red888 using datetime from datetime, `abs((datetime(2016, 6, 21) - datetime(1982, 7, 5)).days)` gives you `12405`

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way is using `python-dateutil`

```
import datetime

import dateutil

def birthday(date):
    # Get the current date
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    now = now.date()

    # Get the difference between the current date and the birthday
    age = dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(now, date)
    age = age.years

    return age
```

Comment: This does not work correctly when the birthday is on Feb. 29 and today's date is Feb. 28 (it will act as if today is Feb. 29).

Comment: Refer to the accepted answer for a solution that is correct and robust with exact accuracy provided months before this one.

Answer (score 7):

```
from datetime import date

def age(birth_date):
    today = date.today()
    y = today.year - birth_date.year
    if today.month < birth_date.month or today.month == birth_date.month and today.day < birth_date.day:
        y -= 1
    return y
```

Comment: date instance or some obj like that, docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date, typo fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, you cannot just use timedelata as the largest unit it uses is day and leap years will render you calculations invalid.  Therefore, let's find number of years then adjust by one if the last year isn't full:

```
from datetime import date
birth_date = date(1980, 5, 26)
years = date.today().year - birth_date.year
if (datetime.now() - birth_date.replace(year=datetime.now().year)).days >= 0:
    age = years
else:
    age = years - 1
```

**Upd:**

This solution really causes an exception when Feb, 29 comes into play.  Here's correct check:

```
from datetime import date
birth_date = date(1980, 5, 26)
today = date.today()
years = today.year - birth_date.year
if all((x >= y) for x,y in zip(today.timetuple(), birth_date.timetuple()):
   age = years
else:
   age = years - 1
```

**Upd2:**

Calling multiple calls to `now()` a performance hit is ridiculous, it does not matter in all but extremely special cases.  The real reason to use a variable is the risk of data incosistency.

Comment: Thank you, I found out this by doing some tests - and ended up a similar code found from AndiDog's link.

Comment: Strike 1: You're using datetime.datetime instead of datetime.date. Strike 2: Your code is ugly and inefficient. Calling datetime.now() **THREE** times?? Strike 3: Birthdate 29 Feb 2004 and today's date 28 Feb 2010 should return age 6, not die shrieking "ValueError: day is out of range for month". You're out!

Comment: Sorry, your "Upd" code is even more baroque and broken than the first attempt -- nothing to do with 29 February; it fails in MANY simple cases like 2009-06-15 to 2010-07-02 ... the person is obviously a little over 1 year old but you deduct a year because the test on the days (2 >= 15) fails. And obviously you haven't tested it -- it contains a syntax error.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking to print this in a page using django templates, then the following might be enough:

```
{{ birth_date|timesince }}
```

Comment: Don't use Django's `|timesince` for calculating a timedelta over several years because it does not account for leap years and thus yields inaccurate results. See Django ticket #19210 for more info on this.

Answer (score 4):

The classic gotcha in this scenario is what to do with people born on the 29th day of February. Example: you need to be aged 18 to vote, drive a car, buy alcohol, etc ... if you are born on 2004-02-29, what is the first day that you are permitted to do such things: 2022-02-28, or 2022-03-01? AFAICT, mostly the first, but a few killjoys might say the latter.

Here's code that caters for the 0.068% (approx) of the population born on that day:

```
def age_in_years(from_date, to_date, leap_day_anniversary_Feb28=True):
    age = to_date.year - from_date.year
    try:
        anniversary = from_date.replace(year=to_date.year)
    except ValueError:
        assert from_date.day == 29 and from_date.month == 2
        if leap_day_anniversary_Feb28:
            anniversary = datetime.date(to_date.year, 2, 28)
        else:
            anniversary = datetime.date(to_date.year, 3, 1)
    if to_date < anniversary:
        age -= 1
    return age

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import datetime

    tests = """

    2004  2 28 2010  2 27  5 1
    2004  2 28 2010  2 28  6 1
    2004  2 28 2010  3  1  6 1

    2004  2 29 2010  2 27  5 1
    2004  2 29 2010  2 28  6 1
    2004  2 29 2010  3  1  6 1

    2004  2 29 2012  2 27  7 1
    2004  2 29 2012  2 28  7 1
    2004  2 29 2012  2 29  8 1
    2004  2 29 2012  3  1  8 1

    2004  2 28 2010  2 27  5 0
    2004  2 28 2010  2 28  6 0
    2004  2 28 2010  3  1  6 0

    2004  2 29 2010  2 27  5 0
    2004  2 29 2010  2 28  5 0
    2004  2 29 2010  3  1  6 0

    2004  2 29 2012  2 27  7 0
    2004  2 29 2012  2 28  7 0
    2004  2 29 2012  2 29  8 0
    2004  2 29 2012  3  1  8 0

    """

    for line in tests.splitlines():
        nums = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
        if not nums:
            print
            continue
        datea = datetime.date(*nums[0:3])
        dateb = datetime.date(*nums[3:6])
        expected, anniv = nums[6:8]
        age = age_in_years(datea, dateb, anniv)
        print datea, dateb, anniv, age, expected, age == expected
```

Here's the output:

```
2004-02-28 2010-02-27 1 5 5 True
2004-02-28 2010-02-28 1 6 6 True
2004-02-28 2010-03-01 1 6 6 True

2004-02-29 2010-02-27 1 5 5 True
2004-02-29 2010-02-28 1 6 6 True
2004-02-29 2010-03-01 1 6 6 True

2004-02-29 2012-02-27 1 7 7 True
2004-02-29 2012-02-28 1 7 7 True
2004-02-29 2012-02-29 1 8 8 True
2004-02-29 2012-03-01 1 8 8 True

2004-02-28 2010-02-27 0 5 5 True
2004-02-28 2010-02-28 0 6 6 True
2004-02-28 2010-03-01 0 6 6 True

2004-02-29 2010-02-27 0 5 5 True
2004-02-29 2010-02-28 0 5 5 True
2004-02-29 2010-03-01 0 6 6 True

2004-02-29 2012-02-27 0 7 7 True
2004-02-29 2012-02-28 0 7 7 True
2004-02-29 2012-02-29 0 8 8 True
2004-02-29 2012-03-01 0 8 8 True
```

Comment: And I recently just learned about the [leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on [Danny's Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9754466/65387), but with all sorts of ways to report ages for younger folk (note, today is `datetime.date(2015,7,17)`):

```
def calculate_age(born):
    '''
        Converts a date of birth (dob) datetime object to years, always rounding down.
        When the age is 80 years or more, just report that the age is 80 years or more.
        When the age is less than 12 years, rounds down to the nearest half year.
        When the age is less than 2 years, reports age in months, rounded down.
        When the age is less than 6 months, reports the age in weeks, rounded down.
        When the age is less than 2 weeks, reports the age in days.
    '''
    today = datetime.date.today()
    age_in_years = today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))
    months = (today.month - born.month - (today.day < born.day)) %12
    age = today - born
    age_in_days = age.days
    if age_in_years >= 80:
        return 80, 'years or older'
    if age_in_years >= 12:
        return age_in_years, 'years'
    elif age_in_years >= 2:
        half = 'and a half ' if months > 6 else ''
        return age_in_years, '%syears'%half
    elif months >= 6:
        return months, 'months'
    elif age_in_days >= 14:
        return age_in_days/7, 'weeks'
    else:
        return age_in_days, 'days'
```

Sample code:

```
print '%d %s' %calculate_age(datetime.date(1933,6,12)) # >=80 years
print '%d %s' %calculate_age(datetime.date(1963,6,12)) # >=12 years
print '%d %s' %calculate_age(datetime.date(2010,6,19)) # >=2 years
print '%d %s' %calculate_age(datetime.date(2010,11,19)) # >=2 years with half
print '%d %s' %calculate_age(datetime.date(2014,11,19)) # >=6 months
print '%d %s' %calculate_age(datetime.date(2015,6,4)) # >=2 weeks
print '%d %s' %calculate_age(datetime.date(2015,7,11)) # days old

80 years or older
52 years
5 years
4 and a half years
7 months
6 weeks
7 days
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import datetime
```

**Todays date**

```
td=datetime.datetime.now().date()
```

**Your birthdate**

```
bd=datetime.date(1989,3,15)
```

**Your age**

```
age_years=int((td-bd).days /365.25)
```

Comment: Pretty much the same answer as submitted by TheOne, except even less accurate. Refer to the accepted answer for a correct and robust answer. This answer is just spam.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution to find age of a person as either years or months or days.

Lets say a person's date of birth is **2012-01-17T00:00:00**
Therefore, his age on **2013-01-16T00:00:00** will be **11 months**

or if he is born on **2012-12-17T00:00:00**, 
his age on **2013-01-12T00:00:00** will be **26 days**

or if he is born on **2000-02-29T00:00:00**,
his age on **2012-02-29T00:00:00** will be **12 years**

You will need to **import datetime**.

Here is the code:

```
def get_person_age(date_birth, date_today):

"""
At top level there are three possibilities : Age can be in days or months or years.
For age to be in years there are two cases: Year difference is one or Year difference is more than 1
For age to be in months there are two cases: Year difference is 0 or 1
For age to be in days there are 4 possibilities: Year difference is 1(20-dec-2012 - 2-jan-2013),
                                                 Year difference is 0, Months difference is 0 or 1
"""
years_diff = date_today.year - date_birth.year
months_diff = date_today.month - date_birth.month
days_diff = date_today.day - date_birth.day
age_in_days = (date_today - date_birth).days

age = years_diff
age_string = str(age) + " years"

# age can be in months or days.
if years_diff == 0:
    if months_diff == 0:
        age = age_in_days
        age_string = str(age) + " days"
    elif months_diff == 1:
        if days_diff < 0:
            age = age_in_days
            age_string = str(age) + " days"
        else:
            age = months_diff
            age_string = str(age) + " months"
    else:
        if days_diff < 0:
            age = months_diff - 1
        else:
            age = months_diff
        age_string = str(age) + " months"
# age can be in years, months or days.
elif years_diff == 1:
    if months_diff < 0:
        age = months_diff + 12
        age_string = str(age) + " months" 
        if age == 1:
            if days_diff < 0:
                age = age_in_days
                age_string = str(age) + " days" 
        elif days_diff < 0:
            age = age-1
            age_string = str(age) + " months"
    elif months_diff == 0:
        if days_diff < 0:
            age = 11
            age_string = str(age) + " months"
        else:
            age = 1
            age_string = str(age) + " years"
    else:
        age = 1
        age_string = str(age) + " years"
# The age is guaranteed to be in years.
else:
    if months_diff < 0:
        age = years_diff - 1
    elif months_diff == 0:
        if days_diff < 0:
            age = years_diff - 1
        else:
            age = years_diff
    else:
        age = years_diff
    age_string = str(age) + " years"

if age == 1:
    age_string = age_string.replace("years", "year").replace("months", "month").replace("days", "day")

return age_string
```

Some extra functions used in the above codes are:

```
def get_todays_date():
    """
    This function returns todays date in proper date object format
    """
    return datetime.now()
```

And

```
def get_date_format(str_date):
"""
This function converts string into date type object
"""
str_date = str_date.split("T")[0]
return datetime.strptime(str_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Now, we have to feed **get_date_format()** with the strings like **2000-02-29T00:00:00**

It will convert it into the date type object which is to be fed to **get_person_age(date_birth, date_today)**.

The function **get_person_age(date_birth, date_today)** will return age in string format.

Answer (score 2):

Extend to [Danny W. Adair Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9754466), to get month also

```
def calculate_age(b):
    t = date.today()
    c = ((t.month, t.day) < (b.month, b.day))
    c2 = (t.day< b.day)
    return t.year - b.year - c,c*12+t.month-b.month-c2
```

Answer (score 1):

As I did not see the correct implementation, I recoded mine this way...

```
    def age_in_years(from_date, to_date=datetime.date.today()):
  if (DEBUG):
    logger.debug("def age_in_years(from_date='%s', to_date='%s')" % (from_date, to_date))

  if (from_date>to_date): # swap when the lower bound is not the lower bound
    logger.debug('Swapping dates ...')
    tmp = from_date
    from_date = to_date
    to_date = tmp

  age_delta = to_date.year - from_date.year
  month_delta = to_date.month - from_date.month
  day_delta = to_date.day - from_date.day

  if (DEBUG):
    logger.debug("Delta's are : %i  / %i / %i " % (age_delta, month_delta, day_delta))

  if (month_delta>0  or (month_delta==0 and day_delta>=0)): 
    return age_delta 

  return (age_delta-1)
```

Assumption of being "18" on the 28th of Feb when born on the 29th is just wrong.
Swapping the bounds can be left out ... it is just a personal convenience for my code :)

Answer (score 0):

import datetime

```
def age(date_of_birth):
    if date_of_birth > datetime.date.today().replace(year = date_of_birth.year):
        return datetime.date.today().year - date_of_birth.year - 1
    else:
        return datetime.date.today().year - date_of_birth.year
```

In your case:

```
import datetime

# your model
def age(self):
    if self.birthdate > datetime.date.today().replace(year = self.birthdate.year):
        return datetime.date.today().year - self.birthdate.year - 1
    else:
        return datetime.date.today().year - self.birthdate.year
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified [Danny's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217488/age-from-birthdate-in-python/9754466#9754466) for easier reading and understanding

```
    from datetime import date

    def calculate_age(birth_date):
        today = date.today()
        age = today.year - birth_date.year
        full_year_passed = (today.month, today.day) < (birth_date.month, birth_date.day)
        if not full_year_passed:
            age -= 1
        return age
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more elegant solution than @DannyWAdairs solution might be to work with the [**`.timetuple()`** method <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.timetuple):

```
from datetime import date

def calculate_age(born):
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - born.year - (today.timetuple()[1:3] < born.timetuple()[1:3])
```

You can easily use this to generalize this further to increase its *granularity* to seconds, such that the age increments if it is greater than or equal to the number of seconds of that day, if `born` is for example a `datetime` object:

```
from datetime import datetime

def calculate_age_with_seconds(born):
    today = datetime.now()
    return today.year - born.year - (today.timetuple()[1:6] < born.timetuple()[1:6])
```

This will work for `born` both being a `date` or a `datetime` object.

Comment: Once you move to datetime objects, you really also have to start considering timezones. Luckily, that's not what the question was about. See also comments on my solution.

Answer (score -1):

`serializers.py`

```
age = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_age')

class Meta:
    model = YourModel
    fields = [..,'','birthdate','age',..]


import datetime

def get_age(self, instance):
    return datetime.datetime.now().year - instance.birthdate.year
```

Answer (score -5):

You can use Python 3 to do all this. Just run the following code and see.

```
# Creating a variables:

greeting = "Hello, "
name = input("what is your name?")
birth_year = input("Which year you were born?")
response = "Your age is "

# Converting string variable to int:

calculation = 2020 - int(birth_year) 


# Printing:

print(f'{greeting}{name}. {response}{calculation}')
```

Comment: Dude, come on... that wouldn't give you the right answer for 11 months of the year if your birthday was in December and you did that calculation in January, as an example ;). Not the way to go.