# ensuring DateField validator above a certain age in django Models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am fairly new to django and I am trying to constrain a django model field such that the age less than 25 years is shown as an error (using the datefield). So, I have the following model:

```
dob = models.DateField(blank=False, )
```

I am wondering how one can apply the above constraint in a django model.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create [custom field validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#writing-validators).

Unfortunately you will need to hardcode the age value inside validator function, since it doesn't allow you to pass any arguments.

Then to calculate age use [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2259711/1566605) to correctly cover leap years.

Answer (score 2):

I've just come across the same problem, and here is my solution for a custom field validator that checks for a minimum age value:

```
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.validators import BaseValidator
from datetime import date

def calculate_age(born):
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - born.year - \
           ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))

@deconstructible
class MinAgeValidator(BaseValidator):
    message = _("Age must be at least %(limit_value)d.")
    code = 'min_age'

    def compare(self, a, b):
        return calculate_age(a) < b
```

The calculate_age snippet is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217488/age-from-birthdate-in-python/9754466#9754466).

Usage:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(validators=[MinAgeValidator(18)])
```

Comment: Your validation class is incomplete. Python Doc says:You can also use a class with a **__call__() method** for more complex or configurable validators. RegexValidator, for example, uses this technique. If a class-based validator is used in the validators model field option, you should make sure it is serializable by the migration framework by adding deconstruct() and __eq__() methods.