# Automated Action Birthday =19

Tags: python, orm, odoo, openerp-8

I have a table called students and i need to check  male students ages every day to know if they  are more than 19 or not  .i know i should run cron function to check the birth dates every day but i need to get the values in the  birth dates column  , do some operations to get the age more than 19 or not , add the students that have age more than 19 to another table.

here is what i did :D help me with what within the comments please :)

Python Code

```
def get_age_comp(self, cr, uid, birth_date,gender , context=None):


  # birth_date and gender are names of columns in fci.students table like :

  #'birth_date': fields.date(string='Birth Date', required=True)

  #'gender': fields.selection([('m', 'Male'), ('f', 'Female')], string='Gender', required=True)


  student_obj = self.pool.get('fci.student')

  current_date = datetime.now()

  current_year = current_date.year

  birth_dates = parser.parse(birth_date)

  current_age = current_year - birth_dates.year

  gender = student_obj.search(cr, uid, [('gender', '=', True), ('gender', 'like', 'm')])

  if current_age > 19 & gender=='m':


  #i don't know if i do it right and i need to insert these students (name ,age ) to table called 'stat'
```

XML CODE

```
<record id="ir_cron_actions" model="ir.cron">
  <field name="name">Check age Job</field>
  <field eval="True" name="active"/>
  <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
  <field name="interval_number">1</field>
  <field name="interval_type">days</field>
  <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
  <field eval="'fci.student'" name="model"/>
  <field eval="'get_age_comp'" name="function"/>
  <field eval="'()'" name="args"/>
</record>
```

Comment: why down vote my question without answer ?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might not be the brightiest way, but you should be able to do something like this :

```
def get_age_comp(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    cr.execute('DELETE FROM stat;')
    cr.execute('''INSERT INTO stat(name, age)
                  SELECT name, date_part('years',age(birth_date))
                  FROM fci_student
                  WHERE gender='m'
                  AND date_part('years',age(birth_date)) > 18;''')
```

if you don't want to drop existing stat rows each time, you could do something like in [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6527838/2001574) about postgresql 'insert or update'

**edit : if you want to use the [new api](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/reference/orm.html)**

you could add these imports :

```
from openerp import api
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
```

then the method could become :

```
@api.model
def get_age_comp(self):
    for student in self.search([('gender','=','m'), ('birth_date', '<=', date.today() - relativedelta(years=20))]):
        self.env.cr.execute('INSERT INTO stat VALUES(%s,%s)', (student.name, student.birthdate))
```

since `stat` doesn't seem to be an odoo model, it's not accessible via the ORM API and we have to use sql.

If I am mistaken and `stat` is an odoo model, the code could become :

```
@api.model
def get_age_comp(self):
    to_add = {}
    # getting all male older than 19 years from fci.student
    for student in self.search([('gender','=','m'), ('birth_date', '<=', date.today() - relativedelta(years=20))]):
        to_add[student.name] = student.birth_date
    # ignoring the students already in stat
    for stat in self.env['stat'].search([('name', 'in', to_add.keys())]):
        del to_add[stat.name]
    # adding the new ones
    for name, birth_date in to_add.iteritems():
        stat_model.create({'name': name, 'birth_date': birth_date})
```

i didn't use age in `stat` here, since it's a bad practice ( it changes at least once every year for every people ) but you could see this question about [calculating age from date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217488/age-from-birthdate-in-python) and mix it in the code.

**edit : for the case added in comment**

> create status in student table (underage-getCard-gotCard) if his
>   age is less than 20, his status should be
>   underage, if he is getting the card his status should be getCard, if he
>   got the card the status should be gotCard..i want to know how to
>   change status in the code :)

if it was the only thing you wanted to do, it could be done with :

```
@api.model
def get_age_comp(self):
    self.search([('gender','=','m'), ('status', '=', 'underage'),
                 ('birth_date', '<=', date.today() - relativedelta(years=20))
                ]).write({'status': 'getCard'})
```

otherway, like done previously, you could loop on `.search()` result :

```
@api.model
def get_age_comp(self):
    for student in self.search([('gender','=','m'), ('birth_date', '<=', date.today() - relativedelta(years=20)), ('status', '=', 'underage')]):
        student.status = 'getCard'
        # do other things here
```

Comment: thanks for your replay but using sql statements is very easy  i need to do it with python ORM.

Comment: i don't see any advantage of the python orm in this case, especially if `stat` is not an odoo model, but i edited my answer with it

Comment: thanks for your help dear dear :D

 
 
could i ask another question ? if i need to just create statues in student table (underage-getCard-gotCard) and i want if his age is more than 19 his status should be underage if he is getting the card his status should be getCard if he get the card the status should be gotCard..i want to know who to change status in the code :) thanks in advance

Comment: you could add the need to be underage in the `search()` domain list `('status', '=', 'underage')`, then in the loop you could add a line like `student.status = 'getCard'`

Comment: ammm no i need to change the status if he has age more than 19,i mean default is underage but if he get 19 + his status should be getCard. :)

Comment: yes that's what I was describing, I added another part in the answer with examples

Comment: that's awesome :D:) could i ask you more if i had more complicated questions :) ? i will be thankful.

Comment: there is the [orm api documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/reference/orm.html) more helpful than what I said here, and if stackoverflow isn't enough, an odoo dedicated [help forum](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1). as for me I only answer when I can, wish and have time.