# Python Length of life

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I am trying to create a program in python that tells you how many days you have lived for. The code I have at the moment is:

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

year = int(input('Enter the year'))
month = int(input('Enter the month'))
day = int(input('Enter the day'))
date1 = datetime.date(year, month, day)

now = datetime.datetime.now().date()

days = now - date1
print days
```

At the moment it prints the number the number of days and then `0:00:00`. For example: `5914 days, 0:00:00`. Does anyone know how to get rid of the `0:00:00`?

Comment: So you just want `(now - date1).days`? The result of the calculation is a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object.

Comment: `>>> print 'days : {}'.format(days.days)`

Comment: reading through this [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) would help greatly

Comment: related: [Age from birthdate in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2217488/4279)

Comment: you could use `from datetime import date; now = date.today()`. You could use `birthday = datetime.strptime(raw_input('Enter birthday as YYYY-MM-DD: '), '%Y-%m-%d')`, to get the birthday at once.

Answer (score 5):

`days` is a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object, so just do `print days.days`