# Django Charfield null=False Integrity Error not raised

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model:

```
class Discount(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=10)
```

In my shell when I try and save a Discount object with no input, it doesn't raise an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
> e = Discount()
> e.save()
```

Comment: What if you do `Discount.objects.create()` instead?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No default Django behavior will save `CHAR` or `TEXT` types as `Null` - it will always use an empty string (`''`). `null=False` has no effect on these types of fields.

`blank=False` means that the field will be required by default when the model is used to render a ModelForm. It does not prevent you from manually saving a model instance without that value.

What you want here is a custom model validator:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
def validate_not_empty(value):
    if value == '':
        raise ValidationError('%(value)s is empty!'), params={'value':value})
```

Then add the validator to your model:

```
code = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=True, validators=[validate_not_empty])
```

This will take care of the form validation you want, but validators don't automatically run when a model instance is saved. [Further reading here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run) If you want to validate this every time an instance is saved, I suggest overriding the default `save` behavior, checking the value of your string there, and interrupting the save by raising an error if necessary. [Good post on overriding `save` here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953427/django-custom-save-model)

[Further reading on `null`:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null)

> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for “no data;” the Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL. One exception is when a CharField has both unique=True and blank=True set. In this situation, null=True is required to avoid unique constraint violations when saving multiple objects with blank values.

[And on validators.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/)

Answer (score 0):

In order for your model to raise an error if a CharField is empty, you just need to override the clean function, like this :

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Discount(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=True)

    def clean(self):
         if self.code == '':
              raise ValidationError('Empty code not allowed')
```

See : [How can you create a non-empty CharField in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940499/)

Answer (score 0):

In the `views.py` you can check if the string is '' , in that case you can send `NONE`. That will raise the integrity error.

Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).