# Serializer behaviour with null=False fields in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've encountered a weird behavior that I don't quite get. For the model

```
class Tenant:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    country = models.CharField(max_lengh=155)
```

I'm using this serializer:

```
class Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tenant
        fields = (name,)
```

This set up will allow me to save a tenant instance that doesn't have a country supplied even though the `null=True` should be enforced on the DB level (Postgres). Only when I add `country` to the fields, will it enforce the `null=False` constraint.

This seems quite unintuitive to me.

---

**Edit: Here is a simple code example of my problem:**

```
class AppModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class CrateAppModel(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = AppModelSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

class AppModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AppModel
        fields = (
            "name",
        )
```

Using simple post requests I'm able to create an instance without a country field. **I don't understand why?** In my database `country` is of type string and empty.

Comment: In this setup, DRF won't raise any ***validation*** error, but upon calling the `save()` method of serializer, PostgreSQL will raise an error, and so Django too

Comment: For my use-case it really doesn't. Something internal is populating the field with an empty string. This is really worrisome for me. But there is nothing in my code to explain this.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue by using ***exact same setup***, Would you mind adding a ***minimal reproducible example***?

Comment: Ok, I just build a small example with a standard app. This seems to be the standard behavior for Django. I will add the code

Comment: I've added the example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Charfield null=False Integrity Error not raised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176618/django-charfield-null-false-integrity-error-not-raised)

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks!