# How can I calculate difference of year and month in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datediff

I have a script that get the date from datetime, and the date from whois service:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
import whois
#date
url='testurl.com'
now = datetime.now()
date1 = datetime.strftime(nowstr,'%Y-%m')
#whois
domain = whois.whois(url)
datestr = domain.creation_date
date2 = datetime.strftime(datestr, '%Y-%m')
```

When i calculate the difference:

```
diff = datetime.strptime(date1,'%Y-%m') - datetime.strptime(date2,'%Y-%m')
print diff
```

it gives me output like:

```
5451 days, 0:00:00
```

How can i get the Output in the format of Years and months(in my case, 14y 11m)?

Answer (score 1):

Take a [look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765797/python-timedelta-in-years).  I believes it answers your question.  It shows both using standard and non-standard python libraries.