# Querying a DateField with a range of 2 years

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is a pretty straight-forward question:

I have two models, each with a DateField. I want to query Model-A based on the date in Model-B. I want a query that returns all the objects of Model-A that have a date within 2 years, plus or minus, of the date in one object of Model-B. How can this be done?

Comment: Form the range (highest and lowest wanted dates) from the date in your model B, then use date__range=['earliest_date', 'latest_date'] in a filter on your objects.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a date value from model `B`, calculate two dates: one - 2 years in the past and another - 2 years in the future by the help of [`python-dateutil`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) module (taken partially from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/765990/771848)). Then, use [`__range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) notation to filter out `A` records by date range:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def yearsago(from_date, years):
    return from_date - relativedelta(years=years)


b_date = b.my_date
date_min, date_max = yearsago(b_date, 2), yearsago(b_date, -2)
data = A.objects.filter(my_date__range=(date_min, date_max))
```

where `b` is a `B` model instance.

Also see: [Django database query: How to filter objects by date range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668619/django-database-query-how-to-filter-objects-by-date-range)

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you're not using `dateutil` you can use `date_min = b_date.replace(year=(b_date.year-2))` - except that you'll have to think about February 29th in leap years.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper yeah, I found `dateutil` more robust. Thanks.

Comment: Personally I'd pass on installing an extra module for this simple a case if I weren't already using `dateutil` - years almost work perfectly with `replace`. But it's clearly a matter of personal preference. If you do use `replace`, also use `calendar.isleap` rather than rolling your own - it's easy to forget the leap year corner cases for centuries.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper yeah, for example, my boss hates external dependencies. And I have a really hard time convincing him to use anything neat and awesome from third-parties :)

Comment: Or come to think of it, you could just test `if b_date.month == 2 and b_date.day == 29:`.