# Convert input string type into date format

Tags: python, datetime

I want to calculate age. I am going to receive the birthday from user and calculate the age. I think I need to convert the Input type into date format. Can someone helps me?

I tried to make a list of [year, month, day]. They are integers and I used the following formula to calculate the age but I ran into the error(int type in callable).

```
Age=(Now.year-Birthday[0])-(Now.month,Now.day)<(Birthday[1],Birthday[2])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Age from birthdate in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217488/age-from-birthdate-in-python)

Comment: You can construct a [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) from 3 integers, which means you will need to first convert the 3 strings into integers (by calling [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)).

Comment: @MrFuppes I studied those answers before. The problem is all of them are not going to get birthday from user. For example my code gets it, split it and make all the Y,M,D integers, but i don't know what is the problem with the formula, because everything is integers.

Comment: @martineau my code gets input it, split it and make all the Y,M,D integers, but i don't know what is the problem with the formula, because everything is integers.

Comment: Once you have two dates, you can subtract them yielding a [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta). You should be able to calculate the age from that.

Comment: Also see [Difference between now and birthdate in years, months, days, mintues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917134/difference-between-now-and-birthdate-in-years-months-days-mintues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By importing `datetime` class *(from `datetime` module, they're called the same, it's confusing)* you can use the strptime() to translate dates from string to Date:

```python
from datetime import datetime
import math

bday_str = '18/04/1998'
bday_date = datetime.strptime(bday_str, '%d/%m/%y')
```

This would get you '18/04/1998' as a Date object, which later on you can use to operate to get the age of the person:

```python
now = datetime.datetime.now()
age = math.trunc((now-bday_date).days/365.2425)
print(age)
>>> 22
```

Comment: `days / 365` would only be approximately the number of years.

Comment: True that, they could import math and do a math.trunc() on the result as age is conventionally always rounded down.

Comment: Actually, just dividing by `365.2425` (the mean Gregorian year) would be an improvement.

Comment: @RogerThat helped me so much. Annoying thing about this lib is from datetime import datetime(???) why?? :))))

Comment: @MohammadrezaShahsavar: See first sentence of answer.

Comment: @martineau I got it. I meant that at the first time I thought it was a mistake. I didn't know that the class and the object, sub-Class can have the same name.

Comment: @Mohammadreza: Oh…and agree the fact that the `datetime` module contains a class in it of the same name _is_ confusing (even if you know that's how it is).