# Count of Year in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime-format, subtraction

How can I find count of year in python from certain date and a date since people opened an account (CRDACCT_DTE_OPEN)? The certain date (MIS_DATE) is 2021-03-01 with format= `'%Y%m%d'`.

The dataset given below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
     { "MIS_DATE": ["2018-03-02", "2020-03-26", "2019-08-17", "2019-08-17", "2019-08-19"],
       "CRDACCT_DTE_OPEN": ["2021-03-31", "2021-03-31", "2021-03-31", "2021-03-31",  "2021-03-31"]})
```

Format date:

```
df['CRDACCT_DTE_OPEN'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CRDACCT_DTE_OPEN'], format='%Y%m%d')
df['MIS_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MIS_DATE'], format='%d%m%Y')
```

I've tried to do this operation. Let's say **MOB** is subtract of **MIS_DATE - CRDACCT_DTE_OPEN**,  but the result is not what I expected. *I want the output in form of year format, for example if someone opened an account in 2018-03-31, hence the MOB is 3.* Meaning that 3 years since that person open an account.

```
MOB = df['MIS_DATE'] - df['CRDACCT_DTE_OPEN']
MOB
```

Output:

```
1        370 days
2        592 days
3        592 days
4        590 days
 ...   

Name: MOB, Length: 5, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Maybe divide days by 365 like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49399967/15497888) or divide by 1Y timedelta like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59960315/15497888). Something like `MOB = (df['MIS_DATE'] - df['CRDACCT_DTE_OPEN']).dt.days // 365` if wanting whole numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy's
`timedelta()`

```
import numpy
(MOB/numpy.timedelta64(1, 'Y')).round()
0    3.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    2.0
4    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it's what I need. Suggestions below are also good, but this answer makes me don't give extra efforts. I just need to convert the results with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

this is what you need.

#### `df['col_of_datetime'].dt.year`

here is the example

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"MIS_DATE": ["2018-03-02", "2020-03-26", "2019-08-17", "2019-08-17", "2019-08-19"],
     "CRDACCT_DTE_OPEN": ["2021-03-31", "2021-03-31", "2021-03-31", "2021-03-31",  "2021-03-31"]})

df['CRDACCT_DTE_OPEN'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CRDACCT_DTE_OPEN'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['MIS_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MIS_DATE'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

target_year = 2021
result = target_year - df['MIS_DATE'].dt.year
print(result)
```

Output:

```
0    3
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
Name: MIS_DATE, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this: Here we are using the `date_range` function from Pandas

```
for x in range(len(df)):
print(len(pd.date_range(start=pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[x][0]),end=pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[x][1]),freq='Y')))

3
1
2
2
2
```

You can change `freq ='M'` for months