# Convert Date of Birth to number age Python

Tags: python

Thanks Everyone, im close.  Im using Python within a survey software tool called Decipher, so it may appear a little different.  My issue now is I need to "pipe" in the age based on a respondents answer, that would be your_date_string.  But when I put that in my dob variable I get an error from the system: ValueError: time data 'your_date_string' does not match format '%Y,%d,%m', but printing the your_date_string returns the exact value needed.  Not sure how to fix this.

```
from datetime import date

your_date_string = str(2003 - (scr_q2c.c1.val)) +","+ str(scr_q2b.c1.val + 1) +","+ str(scr_q2a.c1.val + 1)
year, day, month = [int(f) for f in your_date_string.split(',')]
your_date = date(year, month, day)

dob = datetime.datetime.strptime('your_date_string', '%Y,%d,%m')
today = datetime.date.today()
age = today.year - dob.year - ((today.month, today.day) &lt; (dob .month, dob .day))

print your_date_string
print age
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your actual date format look like? Are the strings all formatted the same?

Comment: dob = str(2003 - (scr_q2c.c1.val)) + "," + str(scr_q2b.c1.val + 1) + "," + str(scr_q2a.c1.val + 1)


from datetime import date    
age = date.today()-date(dob)
print(age)
 
print dob

Comment: use `datetime`.

Comment: Could you add that to your question? It's hard to read in a comment

Comment: What is wrong with your solution?  You might make use of [`date.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Im getting an issue where the system is telling me "an integer is required" for dob.  But I tried converting to int and still no luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python timedelta in years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765797/python-timedelta-in-years)

Comment: When asking a question about code that throws an exception, please post the complete Traceback - copy it and paste it into your question then format it as code ... https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: I just need to convert your_date_string to a useable variable in my dob variable.  When I manually input 1982,14,4 it works, just doesnt work when I use the variable name.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to convert your string to a date object:

```
from datetime import date

your_date_string = '1982,14,4'
year, day, month = [int(f) for f in your_date_string.split(',')]
your_date = date(year, month, day)
```

And then use that date object to compute the number of years. A quick and easy way to do that is to rely on `dateutil` third-party library that you can install using `pip install dateutil`. Here is an example:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

difference_in_years = relativedelta(date.today(), your_date).years
```

In this example, `difference_in_years = 35`.

Answer (score 0):

check the month and day, if today less than date of birth than minus one from year difference

```
import datetime
dob = datetime.datetime.strptime('1982,14,4', '%Y,%d,%m')
today = datetime.date.today()
print today.year - dob.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (dob .month, dob .day))
```