# Using datetime.timedelta to add years

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta, python-dateutil

I am doing some time calculations in Python.

#### Goal:

Part of this is trying to :

*Given a date, add time interval (X years, X months, X weeks), return date*

ie

- input args: input_time (datetime.date), interval (datetime.timedelta)
- return: datetime.date

I looked at the datetime and [datetime.timedelta docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)

> class datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0)¶.

These seem to work well if I want to add a certain number of hours or weeks. However,

#### Problem:

- I am trying to implement an operation such as *date + 1 year* and can't figure it out

E.g.

```
start = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
# expected output: datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1)


# with the weeks, etc arguments given in timedelta, this fails unsurprisingly e.g 
start + datetime.timedelta(weeks = 52)

# returns datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 30, 0, 0)
```

#### Question

- Is this year-based operation possible with the basic tools of datetime - if so, how would I go about it?
- I realize that for the year example, I could just do `start.replace(year = 2001)`, but that approach will fail if I have months or weeks as input.
- From my understanding, the *dateutil* library has more advanced features, but I was not clear how well it interacts with the in-built datetime objects.

I have reviewed this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765797/python-timedelta-in-years)  but it did not help me with this.

Any help is much appreciated!

Running Python 3.6.5 on MacOs.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`timedelta` does not support years, because the duration of a year depends on which year (for example, leap years have Feb 29).

You could use a [`relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) instead (from PyPI package [`python-dateutil`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/)) which does support `years` and takes into account the baseline date for additions.

```
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.date(2020, 2, 29)
>>> d
datetime.date(2020, 2, 29)
>>> d + relativedelta(years=1)
datetime.date(2021, 2, 28)
```

Comment: thanks, this looks really good & I figured re the part with leap years...Looking at the [docs](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#relativedelta-examples) for relativdelta, they consistently use the syntax `years=+1` , where you use `years=1`. Testing out, they seem to do the same thing, or is there a difference between the two?

Comment: @patrick probably too late to your comment about the syntax `years=+1`; it means going forward or back, so if you had to go back one year, you would do `years=-1`. From the docs: `Relative information, may be negative (argument is plural); adding or subtracting a relativedelta with relative information performs the corresponding aritmetic operation on the original datetime value with the information in the relativedelta.`

Answer (score 18):

You can hard code a new year value of the datetime using replace instead :)

**Note** that if the current date happens to be the 29th of February, this will raise a `ValueError` with the message: "Day is out of range for month". So you need to handle this special case also:

```
from datetime import datetime
current = datetime.today()
if (current.month == 2) and (current.day == 29):
    year_later = current.replace(year=current.year+1, month=current.month+1, day=1)
else:
    year_later = current.replace(year=current.year+1)
```

Comment: But what about leap years if current is Feb 29?

Comment: @MDoe Good point. I've edited the answer to handle this special case.

Comment: Just to be extremely pedantic for everyone's edification, you might not want 2025-02-28 for the "year ahead" date for 2024-02-29... depending on the use case you might consider that the "equivalent" year-ahead date is 2025-03-01!

Comment: @mikerodent Well, you are right, I corrected the answer

Answer (score 5):

My quick and dirty method is to use

```
y = [number of years]
timedelta(days= y * 365)
```

I found this question looking for a more elegant solution. For my uses a precise answer wasn't necessary. I don't mind losing a day each leap year in this particular case.

Comment: this wouldn't work if you want the day not to change. Meaning, with 3-March-2021, the 365 would make it `4-March-2022`.

Answer (score 0):

My goal was very similar to yours. I wanted to have the same date, just on the next year. But i figured i can't avoid accounting for leap years. In the end it all boils down to what exactly is the requirement. Theoretically we can just add 365 days (and either loose a day when there was a Feb 29), or check in the next 365 days if there is a 29th of February, in which case add 1 more day.
But checking that would have been complex, and in the end i used a simple check for the new date's day if it is different from the original and then add 1 more day.
I understand with dateutil.relativedelta it is easier, but i wanted to do it without extra imports

**demo**:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dates = [datetime(1999, 1, 1),
         datetime(1999, 12, 31),
         datetime(2000, 1, 1),
         datetime(2019, 3, 1),
         datetime(2019, 1, 1),
         datetime(2020, 1, 1),
         datetime(2020, 3, 1),
         datetime(2020, 2, 29)
         ]
for date in dates:
    plus1year_date = date + timedelta(days=365)
    print(date, "\t - original date")
    print(plus1year_date, "\t - plus1year_date (+365 days)")
    if date.day != plus1year_date.day:
        plus1year_date = plus1year_date + timedelta(days=1)
        print(plus1year_date, "\t - plus1year_date adjusted for leap year")
    else:
        print("No need to adjust for leap year")
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------')

# Expected output:
# 1999-01-01 00:00:00    - original date
# 2000-01-01 00:00:00    - plus1year_date (+365 days)
# No need to adjust for leap year
# --------------------------------------------------------------
# 1999-12-31 00:00:00    - original date
# 2000-12-30 00:00:00    - plus1year_date (+365 days)
# 2000-12-31 00:00:00    - plus1year_date adjusted for leap year
# --------------------------------------------------------------
# 2000-01-01 00:00:00    - original date
# 2000-12-31 00:00:00    - plus1year_date (+365 days)
# 2001-01-01 00:00:00    - plus1year_date adjusted for leap year
# --------------------------------------------------------------
# ...
```

Edit: [@MDoe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54394327/using-datetime-timedelta-to-add-years#comment112204994_55153593) - I forgot to mention that with the **.year + 1** method one can end up with invalid dates if it is Feb 29 (*ValueError*).
Also if somebody wants to add an interval that could include more than one leap year, then my code won't be correct.

[date](/questions/tagged/date)[adding-year](/questions/tagged/adding-year)[python](/questions/tagged/python)[datetime](/questions/tagged/datetime)[timedelta](/questions/tagged/timedelta)