# Converting datetime days to years

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

So I'm trying to calculate the difference between the date now with the DOB and came up with a column 'Age'

My codes are

```
df = df.rename(columns={'dob Y':'Year','dob M':'Month','dob D':'Day'})
df = df.head(13)


import datetime
#df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Day','Month','Year']])
df['Age'] = (datetime.datetime.now()-pd.to_datetime(df[['Day','Month','Year']]))

df['Age']
# [i.days for i in df['Age']]
```

However I've gotten the age in days instead

```
0    3381 days 01:44:57.149175
1    3513 days 01:44:57.149175
2    3132 days 01:44:57.149175
3    3740 days 01:44:57.149175
4    4551 days 01:44:57.149175
5    3205 days 01:44:57.149175
6    3814 days 01:44:57.149175
7    5820 days 01:44:57.149175
8    4533 days 01:44:57.149175
9    2445 days 01:44:57.149175
10   2665 days 01:44:57.149175
11   5528 days 01:44:57.149175
12   3707 days 01:44:57.149175
Name: Age, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I've tried to divide by 365.25 but the unit given is still days (as shown below)

```
0     9 days 06:09:54.223747
1     9 days 14:50:18.864404
2     8 days 13:48:13.197053
3    10 days 05:45:15.784322
4    12 days 11:02:38.084117
5     8 days 18:36:01.369537
6    10 days 10:37:00.507114
7    15 days 22:25:40.424979
8    12 days 09:51:40.178572
9     6 days 16:39:43.135451
10    7 days 07:07:04.203213
11   15 days 03:14:27.735041
12   10 days 03:35:09.624158
Name: Age, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I'm trying to round off the Age to years in 2 decimal place. Example 12.96 years

Comment: Have you tried `df['Age'].seconds / (365.25*3600)`

Comment: Yes I did, i get this error instead when I do that "'Series' object has no attribute 'seconds'"

Comment: Sorry, I should have said `df['Age'].dt.total_seconds() / (365.25*24*3600)`.  Try that.

Answer (score 1):

Due to issues explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/765862/10808930), it is impossible to get the exact number of years from a number of days due to variations in year length.

If you want to use 365.25 (or 365.2425, as the linked post suggests) as the number of days in a year, you could do something like this:

```
df['Age'] = pd.to_numeric((datetime.datetime.now()-pd.to_datetime(df[['Day','Month','Year']])).days / 365.2425)
```

Including the int() cast so that we don't get a long decimal.

Comment: I will get this error instead "cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>"

Comment: ah, you have to use the pandas method of converting for a dataframe. I've updated the code above