# how to extract year in date field of date of birth and calculate age of person in django views.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to do this in views.py

```
ExtractYear(date_of_birth) - today.year
```

But it gives error to use int, and i tried like:

```
int (ExtractYear(date_of_birth) )- int(today.year)
```

and it gives error of int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ExtractYear'

and also if i try to do this:

```
date_of_birth_year - today.year
```

it gives error of name 'date_of_birth_year' is not defined

also i did:

```
import datetime
```

I just wanted to find age of person in integer and i don't know how to extract year, hours etc things in datefield or datetime field kindly help.

Comment: The age of a person does not only depends on the year. For example if a person is born on the first of February, then in January, he is one year younger than in March for example.

Comment: I just wanted to extract year, this thing is not my preference yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The age of a person does not only depends on the year. For example, if a person is born on the first of February, then the first of January, he/she is one year younger than the first of March.

You can annotate your person with:

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractYear

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    date_of_birth_year=ExtractYear('date_of_birth_year')
)
```

The `MyModel`s that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.date_of_birth_year` that contains the year of the `date_of_birth`. You can also annotate a field `age` that contains the "age" of the person:

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractYear
from django.utils.timezone import now

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    age=now().year - ExtractYear('date_of_birth_year')
)
```

But this age is thus not *exactly* correct.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution could be:

```
from django.db.models import F, ExpressionWrapper
from django.db.models.functions import Now 

Model.objects.annotate(
    delta = ExpressionWrapper(
    Now() - F('date_of_birth'), output_field=models.DateTimeField()
  )
)
```

Then, the `instance.delta` will be `datetime.timedelta(..)` instance, a little bit [math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765797/python-timedelta-in-years) needed for further processing. Also, Django doc has a similar example, [check it out](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations)