# How to substract 5 years from a date in python

Tags: python

I have a list with date, I want to substract 5 years from it.

I have tried the below code but it's not working.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
s = ["2018-06-19"]
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(s[0], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')-relativedelta(years=5))
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You can look at this answer as I think this will solve your problem :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765797/python-timedelta-in-years.

If this URL is useful, please close your question as it is a duplicate.

Comment: Why do you turn it back into a string *before* trying to subtract from it?

Comment: You're immediately converting your `datetime` object back into a string, and *then* trying to subtract the `relativedelta` object from it.  You need to do the subtraction before the `.strftime()`.

Comment: Thank you. It solved the issue. Quite silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Returns a string, thus is cannot be substracted with a relativedelta. Datetime objects can be substracted. Hence, convert your date to string **after** you do the substraction

```
print((datetime.datetime.strptime(s[0], '%Y-%m-%d')-relativedelta(years=5)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```