# How do I subtract 5 years from a date column to create a new column in python data frame?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I tried this code:

```
df['ExperienceDate'] = (df['IssueDate']) - relativedelta(years=5)
```

It shows an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'relativedelta'

Answer (score 0):

you can check [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765797/python-timedelta-in-years). You can't compare relativedelta object with timedelta. And there is no timedelta as big as year

A solution keeping the same module datetime :

```
diff=timedelta(days=(5*365)) # convert the number of year into a number of day
df['ExperienceDate']= df['IssueDate']-diff # then substract
```

Result :

```
    IssueDate   ExperienceDate
0   1995-02-01  1990-02-02
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
df['ExperienceDate'] = df['IssueDate'].apply(lambda x:x - relativedelta(years=5))
```