# Get date 'hours ago' from now

Tags: python, date

I want to get the exact date from now. I have an input dataframe like shown below. Age columns is difference of date.

And I want to get the shown output dataframe. It is the date calculated as date = current date - difference(AGE data).

Is there any way available?

Input:

```
          AGE
0 '1 years 2 days ago'
1 '3 hours 4 mins ago'
2 '5 mins 6 secs ago'
     ...
```

Output:

```
        DATE
0 2020-07-29 20:00
1 2021-07-31 16:57
2 2021-07-31 19:55
```

Comment: Try converting your input to [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) instance then subtract timedelta from datetime.now() object.

Answer (score 3):

Since your string are quite simple, you could use [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) instead of implementing your own parser. It will convert your strings to datetime objects automagically.

You can then use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to print the datetime object in your format of choice.

For example:

```py
import dateparser
timestrings = ['1 years 2 days ago' ,'3 hours 4 mins ago','5 mins 6 secs ago']

for timestring in timestrings:
    dt = dateparser.parse(timestring)
    print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
```

Output:

```
2020-07-29 22:33
2021-07-31 19:29
2021-07-31 22:28
```

Comment: That's a clever solution! But it has a problem: If you set `df = pd.DataFrame({'AGE': ["59 secs ago"] * 100})` and then look at `df.AGE.map(dateparser.parse)` you will notice that you get slightly different dates. That's due to the shifting base date (time in this case). I've skimmed over the dateparser docs and couldn't find a way to configure the base. Do you know a fix? (Maybe it doesn't matter in the use case the op is interested in.)

Comment: @Timus I think it's a feature: if you are dealing with relative time, usually it's relative to now. Anyway in the [docs](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dateparser.html#dateparser.conf.Settings) there is a flag to do that.

Just pass a datetime object to use as base time and the problem is solved. Try `df.AGE.apply(dateparser.parse, settings={"RELATIVE_BASE" : reference})` where reference is a datetime object.

Comment: I get that it's mostly a feature, but perhaps not in this case :)) (`dateparser` is rather slow - understandably, because it checks for a lot more possibilities than the ones here -, so depending on the size of the data this could indeed be an issue.) Good to know that the behaviour can be modified.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of would be to subtract your time from the current time using time delta (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38245441/14068351)).

This is a simple example:

```py
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
t1 = timedelta(days = 1, hours=7, minutes=36, seconds=20)
print(datetime.now()-t1)
```

Unfortunately, things get more complicated when you add years because of things like leap years.

[This computerphile video](https://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY) by Tom Scott explains in detail the problems you may encounter when working with time.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/765990/14068351) stack overflow question explains how this can still be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Another version that includes months:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

units = ("sec", "min", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year")
re_offset = re.compile("|".join(r"\d+\s*" + f"{unit}s?" for unit in units))
re_num_unit = re.compile(r"(\d+)\s*(\w+)")

def offset(s):
    keys = {
        "sec": "seconds", "secs": "seconds",
        "min": "minutes", "mins": "minutes",
        "hour": "hours", "day": "days", "week": "weeks",
        "month": "months", "year": "years"
    }

    values = {}
    for num_unit in re_offset.findall(s):
        num_str, unit = re_num_unit.match(num_unit).groups()
        unit = keys.get(unit, unit)
        values[unit] = int(num_str)

    return pd.DateOffset(**values)

df["DATE"] = (dt.datetime.now() - df.AGE.apply(offset)).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

or shorter in case the strings behave really well:

```
def offset(lst):
    keys = {
        "sec": "seconds", "secs": "seconds",
        "min": "minutes", "mins": "minutes",
        "hour": "hours", "day": "days", "week": "weeks",
        "month": "months", "year": "years"
    }
    return pd.DateOffset(
        **{keys.get(unit, unit): int(num_str) for num_str, unit in lst}
    )

df["DATE"] = (dt.datetime.now()
              - df.AGE.str.findall(r"(\d+)\s*(\w+)")
                      .map(offset)).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

---

Old version:

```
import re
import datetime as dt

units = ("sec", "min", "hour", "day", "week", "year")
re_timedelta = re.compile("|".join(r"\d+\s*" + f"{unit}s?" for unit in units))
re_num_unit = re.compile(r"(\d+)\s*(\w+)")

def ago(s, now):
    keys = {
        "sec": "seconds", "secs": "seconds",
        "min": "minutes", "mins": "minutes",
        "hour": "hours", "day": "days", "week": "weeks", "year": "years"
    }
    values = {"seconds": 0, "minutes": 0, "hours": 0, "days": 0, "weeks": 0}
    
    for num_unit in re_timedelta.findall(s):
        num_str, unit = re_num_unit.match(num_unit).groups()
        unit = keys.get(unit, unit)
        if unit == "years":
            years = int(num_str)
            if now.month == 2 and now.day == 29 and years%4:
                ago_date = dt.date(now.year - years, 3, 1)
            else:
                ago_date = dt.date(now.year - years, now.month, now.day)
            values["days"] += (now.date() - ago_date).days
        else:
            values[unit] += int(num_str)
    
    return (now - dt.timedelta(**values)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

With that preparation you can do (`df` your dataframe):

```
now = dt.datetime.now()
df["DATE"] = df.AGE.apply(ago, args=[now])
```

Result:

```
                  AGE              DATE
0  1 years 2 days ago  2020-07-29 17:51
1  3 hours 4 mins ago  2021-07-31 14:47
2   5 mins 6 secs ago  2021-07-31 17:46
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do something like that, we can use the date module to get the exact date and time and compare it to the input. Here is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime

#Get the current year (I will make a simpler version, only with the year, it will be the same idea for days, months, etc.)
currentYear = datetime.now().strftime("%Y")

#Input the year to be substracted
secondYear = int(input("What is the year to be substracted?"))

#We will use the int() function on the currentYear variable because normally it is a string type var
#Substract the two years
print(int(currentYear) - secondYear)
```

I hope you understood what I was trying to say, I used a simpler example just to show you how it's done. You can use the same technique on the other dates.